# Row Level Security for Power BI

Tags: dax, powerbi-desktop, row-level-security

This is kind of an odd situation and I am pretty new to RLS so please forgive me if what I am asking about here might seem a little silly. I am trying to create Row Level Security for a School District. I have a table that has the different schools codes, employee IDs and their position. I have another table that has the employee ID for teachers and their Teacher ID along with the ID if the students they have for the current year with a separate row for each bell period.
I have tried to create a bridge table that contains the Employee ID, Teacher ID as well as the School Codes and connected it with the other two tables.
For testing purposes, I am trying to connect it to the students basic information and set security to see how to give teachers access. I feel like I am almost there but I might be missing something out in here.
Can you please tell me how to go forward from here. Thank you

Comment: Is the teacher ID or employee ID their email address?

Comment: No, it is just basic user ID .